# How do I do an Input validation in cshtml?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio, razor

I am trying to do an input validation such that I let the user input a number and I want to check that it is a number. When I click a submit button I want it to check if it is a number. If it is I want a message saying successfully added else an error message saying please input valid number. This is the code I currently have for the input textbox and submit button. How would I proceed to adding the validation and error messages?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="hours" name="hours" type="text" pattern="\d{1,2}" title="NumberOfHoursAlloted" value=@ViewBag.Hours>
    <input class="btn btn-block" type="submit" onclick="verifyCheckboxes()" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

At least on google chrome `pattern="\d{1,2}"` should only allow you to insert the numbers 1 or 2. Please see the code bellow. Using javascript, this is looking to see if you are entering a number or not. To do this, I am using `isNaN() Function`. You can read more about that from this link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

```js
myform = document.getElementById('myform');
myform.addEventListener('submit', verifyCheckboxes);
function verifyCheckboxes(e)
{
    let user_value = document.getElementById("hours").value;
     
    if(isNaN(user_value))//determines whether a value is an illegal number
  {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Please enter a numaric value";
    e.preventDefault();//This will prevent the form from going to action_page.php
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Your input is valid. Redirecting you to action_page.php");
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myform" action="/action_page.php">
  <label>Enter number of hours:</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="hours" name="hours" type="text" title="NumberOfHoursAlloted"> 
  <div style="color: red" id="demo"></div>
  <input class="btn btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```